# How to create type for reference object in TypeScript React app with useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, reference

I create reference for object in TypeScript React app:

```
const inPropsRef = useRef({low: 10, high: 80, min: 0, max: 100})
```

And I need to type my reference object. I searched a lot of info, but everything is related to component reference type. I tried different ways, but every time get errors:

RefObject with generic:

```
// TS2339: Property 'low' does not exist on type 'Range | null'.

interface Range {
  low: number
  high: number
  min: number
  max: number
}

const inPropsRef: RefObject<Range> = useRef({low: 10, high: 80, min: 0, max: 100})
```

Ref type with generic:

```
// TS2339: Property 'low' does not exist on type 'Range | null'.

interface Range {
  low: number
  high: number
  min: number
  max: number
}
const inPropsRef: Ref<Range> = useRef({low: 10, high: 80, min: 0, max: 100})
```

Just interface:

```
// TS2339: Property 'current' does not exist on type 'Range'.

interface Range {
  low: number
  high: number
  min: number
  max: number
}
const inPropsRef: Range = useRef({low: 10, high: 80, min: 0, max: 100})
```

Please can somebody help me how to write the correct type for the object reference.

Comment: Okay I can make a codesanbox where everything works even without typing it explicitly. So generally I think you are okay without even passing a type. I did, sometimes, get conflicting types though, where the ref result was `default | null` as you point out here which would require filtering out the null state. I can't reliably repro though. The types I'm looking at don't union with null either. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

You type the `useRef` hook.

Example:

```
interface Range {
  low: number;
  high: number;
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

const inPropsRef = useRef<Range>({low: 10, high: 80, min: 0, max: 100});
```

Comment: Drew but how about if i want to sent my ref like an argument to the function which type it will be?

Comment: @jocoders I think it'd be something like `React.RefObject<Range>`.

Comment: @jocoders That seems related to something *other than* typing the `useRef` hook. What is `SliderRange`? Is this some other issue related to using the `inPropsRef` variable? If it is actually related then perhaps you've not posted a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code you've an issue working with. Can you update your question/post?

Comment: In case of React.RefObject<Range> type I get the same error: Property 'max' does not exist on type 'Range | null'.  - I had different name, but the error is the same. I have just object ref with the same interface and i create ref in custom hook and after sent it to the component